# Reading values from dynamically added userform controls vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel vba form in which different controls are added dynamically, but when I try to read the values of these so called controls I cannot find them. My code looks like this:

```css
Private Sub CommandButtonAddIndependentParameters_Click()


    Dim theComboBoxIndependentParameterNameNo As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim theLabelIndependentParameterNo As MSForms.Label

    
    iii = iii + 1


    If iii <= 2 Then
       

        Set theComboBoxIndependentParameterNameNo = FrameMeasurement.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", _
            "ComboBoxIndependentParameterNameNo", True)
   
        Set theLabelIndependentParameterNo = FrameMeasurement.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", _
            "LabelIndependentParameterNo" & iii + 1, True)
        
        With theComboBoxIndependentParameterNameNo
            .Font.Name = "B Nazanin"
            .Font.Size = 12
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
            .Height = 24
            .Left = 60
            .Top = 66 + 40 * (iii)
            .Width = 100
            .AddItem (Range("AN2").Value)
            .AddItem (Range("AN3").Value)
            .AddItem (Range("AN4").Value)
        End With
        
        With theLabelIndependentParameterNo
            .Font.Name = "B Nazanin"
            .Font.Size = 12
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
            .Caption = iii + 1
            .Width = 14
            .Height = 18
            .Left = 161
            .Top = 66 + 40 * (iii)
            .AutoSize = False
       End With
        
    End If

End Sub
```

And then I try to read the inserted value by using the following code:

```css
Range("A2").Value = ComboBoxIndependentParameterNameNo2.Value
```

Comment: Inside your UserForm code (not a module code), try using using `Control(NAME_OF_YOUR_CONTROL).Value` to extract the value.  I remember some limitation of accessing dynamically added control values directly in VBA code; I believe that "direct access" names are compiled at runtime and you have to dynamically access dynamically added code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how do I dynamically access multiple controls at runtime?

Comment: Sorry, the exact code should have been `UserForm1.Controls(NAME).Value` for the example above .  To loop through multiple controls, you can use `For Each cControl In UserForm1.Controls` and then use `cControl.Value` inside the for loop to access individual controls.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you need the .value in your code next to the control when you apply it to the cell and use the control itself. Try this:

`Range("A2").Value = theComboBoxIndependentParameterNameNo`

---

'I also found another answer someone else had done:

```
Dim oneControl As Object

For Each oneControl In userform.Controls
    If TypeName(oneControl) = "TextBox" Then
        With oneControl
            Range("M9") = .Value
        End With
    End If
```